# How to run Groovy script with java command?

Tags: java, groovy, scripting

Trying to get the following script:

```
class MyClass {
  static void main(String... args) {
    println "Hello ${args[0]}"
  }
}
```

To run like Java with: `java MyTest John` for example.

Reading [the groovy docs on scripts with main](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_public_static_void_main_vs_script) I was under the impression I could to the following to achieve my goal:

1. Run `groovyc MyTest.groovy`
2. Run `java MyTest John`

I was even under the impression that I could leave just the body of the main function and still be able to compile until a class that extends from `Script`...

I can run the script with `groovy MyTest.groovy John` and (after compiling with `groovyc`) `groovy MyTest John`

How can I accomplish my goal? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need groovy on the classpath when you run the `java` command, ie:

Save this as `MyClass.groovy`

```
class MyClass {
  static main(args) {
    println "Hello ${args[0]}"
  }
}
```

Then run:

```
groovyc MyClass.groovy
```

Then run:

```
java -cp $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:. MyClass John
```

Comment: Crazy how 1 year old tutorials are already outdated on that matter. Most of them point to `-cp $GROOVY_HOME/lib` or don't point to anything at all.

Comment: You can get the individual jars from `lib`, but I tend to point to `all` as they I don't have to think which jars I might need ;-)